# Include metrics of Namespaces where filtering label is undefined

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a PromQL query in Grafana that returns the CPU usage of all Namespaces in my Kubernetes cluster, aggregated by a Namespace label called `risk`:

```
sort_desc(
sum(
max(kube_namespace_labels{label_risk="$risk_query"}) by (label_risk, namespace)
*
on(namespace) group_right(label_risk)
sum by (namespace)
(avg_over_time(namespace:container_cpu_usage:sum{}[$__range]))) BY (label_risk))
```

As you can see, the query is filtered by the Grafana query variable `risk_query`, which is defined like this:

```
label_values(kube_namespace_labels, label_risk)
```

To an extent, this query functions as intended: The dashboard's user can select any existing `risk` Namespace label value in the drop-down menu, and they will see the CPU usage of all Namespaces that have the `risk` label set to that particular value.

**The problem** is that the user must also have a working "All" option for this variable, such that the query returns CPU usage of all Namespaces, even the ones that don't have the `risk` label defined. Unfortunately, using the "Include All option" for the `risk_query` variable returns "No data", whether we use the Custom all value of `<blank>` or `""`. The only way I can figure how to include CPU usage of all Namespaces is by completely removing `{label_risk="$risk_query"}` from the query, but that makes filtering impossible.

**In summary**, how can I keep the feature of filtering this query but also allow the user to see CPU usage of all Namespaces when desired?

Comment: Try using `.*` as `all` value for this variable in Grafana, plus change the `label_appcode="$risk_query"` with `label_appcode=~"$risk_query"` in all the queries on the dashboard

Comment: Many thanks, @valyala! Apologies, I had made a typo in the original question, I should have used `label_risk="$risk_query", but I corrected it. I also posted an answer from your comment, I hope that is OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @valyala for pointing me in the right direction to solve this problem.

Firstly, when defining the `risk_query` query variable in Grafana, use `.*` as the "Custom all value".

Second, use `{label_risk=~"$risk_query"}` instead of `{label_risk="$risk_query"}`:

```
sort_desc(
sum(
max(kube_namespace_labels{label_risk=~"$risk_query"}) by (label_risk, namespace)
*
on(namespace) group_right(label_risk)
sum by (namespace)
(avg_over_time(namespace:container_cpu_usage:sum{}[$__range]))) BY (label_risk))
```

The [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) explains why this expression works even for Namespaces that do not have `label_risk` defined:

> Label matchers that match empty label values also select all time series that do not have the specific label set at all.